# Remove IE Edge compatibility for particular aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer

We are currently developing project with IE edge Compatibility so we added below code in web.config for making compatibility for all pages

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

so now I want to remove this compatibility for particular page alone how its possible, kindly suggest some solution to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code on the particular page

`<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
</head>`

options include:IE=5, IE=7, IE=8,IE=edge

OR

Add the below code on the page load of that particular page

`Response.ClearHeaders();
 Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=5");`

Comment: We have tried this but what happens we have added the compatibility in web.config so its not affected

Comment: Try the second way